# Sass on Grunt always creates an empty output

Tags: javascript, sass, gruntjs, node-sass, grunt-contrib-sass

I'm trying to compile SASS using `grunt-contrib-sass`, but I get an empty CSS file.

Here is the simplest `package.json` I could come up with to compile SASS/SCSS:

```
{
  "name": "sassgrunt",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "sass": "node-sass"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "^1.0.1",
    "grunt-contrib-sass": "^1.0.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.7.2",
    "sass": "^1.0.0-beta.4"
  }
}
```

And this is about as simple as a SCSS file can get:

```
body {
    background: red;
}
```

And this `gruntfile.js`:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        sass: {
            dist: {
                files: {
                    './test.css': './test.scss'
                }
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');
};
```

If I execute `grunt sass`, it creates a brand new and *empty* `test.css` file.

I think I know why.

This command creates a perfectly okay `test2.css` from my source:

```
npm run sass test.scss test2.css
```

But this one just outputs the compiled CSS to the display and creates an empty file:

```
npm run sass test.scss
```

When I run `grunt sass`, that's exactly what I see. Which means that `grunt-contrib-sass` doesn't specify the command line correctly.

I don't understand why, because this setup is exactly what is shown in every example I've seen. Certainly, there must be something wrong with my setup, or everyone would have this issue?

Answer (score 0):

There may be something else amiss, but I think `grunt-contrib-sass` is simply a dud.

I replaced it with `grunt-sass`, and it works perfectly with the same gruntfile setup. Just install using NPM or Yarn and replace `grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');` with `grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-sass');`.